# What percent of data are below the z-score of $z=-1.5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, statistics

A class average for a test is $75$ with a standard deviation of $6$. How can I use this to calculate the percent of ata that are below the $z$ score of $z=-1.50$. The possible solutions are &6.81%, 6.68%, 7.35%, 8.08%&

Comment: Do you have a z-score table?  This just asks you to read it.  Have you tried?

Comment: I do ill take a look at it, I couldn't make much sense of it!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) has a nice figure that shows what the z-scores mean in the table it gives.

Comment: I am still confused how to read it, but thank you!

Comment: The table shows the fraction of the area from the mean to mean+the number of sigma shown.  A z-score of $+1$, $(1 \sigma$ above the mean) means you are above the 50% below the mean and 34.134% above the mean, so there are 15.866% above you.  In your problem, the data is below the mean, so you need to use the symmetry of the normal distribution.

Comment: @RossMillikan so the solution would be 6.68%?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

The table shows the fraction of the area from the mean to mean+the number of sigma shown. A z-score of $+1$, (1σ above the mean) means you are above the $50\%$ below the mean and $34.134\%$ above the mean, so there are $15.866\%$ above you. In your problem, the data is below the mean, so you need to use the symmetry of the normal distribution.

Comment: could you edit in how the answer would be 6.68? then I could accept it

Comment: thanks for your submission