# How many students achieved a higher mark?

Tags: statistics

On a recent test wrote by $34$ students, the class average was $82\%$ and the standard deviation was $6\%$. If Keri's mark was $74\%$, how many students achieved a higher mark then her?

[image]

Below is a picture I drew of the curve. It didn't mention it was a normal curve in the question but below is the graph I drew. I noticed with the mean test mark and the standard deviation her mark does not fall on one of these standard deviations, so how would I find the percentage of students that were above this mark? Is there possibly a error in the question? or is there another method I can use to solve this question

Comment: Your percentages do not add up to $100\%$.  The outer ones should be much smaller.  The assumption of a normal distribution is a good on for a class and a terrible one for real life.  Have you seen a z-score table?  Please look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525290/what-percent-of-data-are-below-the-z-score-of-z-1-5) where the same sort of thing came up.

Comment: so my workings are incorrect? I am really not sure what to do then

Comment: The outer $13.5$s should be $2.5$

Comment: gotcha, but 82-6= 76 and his mark is 74? so how would I do this?

Comment: That was my point about a z-score table.  The score is $\frac 43\sigma$ low.  The table tells you what percentage of the scores are below that.

Comment: if you could add an answer that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My answer would just be that the score is $\frac 43 \sigma$ low and you should look it up in the table.  In my linked answer I gave an explanation of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the given information to calculate z-score using the following formula:

$z = (x - \mu) / \sigma$

$z = (.74 - .82)/ .06 = -(4/3)$

As they said in the comments, you can use the table to interpret this.

Comment: so then how many students would be below?